# How to present the children of a model in django html

Tags: django

I have a blog listing page that displays some header text and then a list of individual blog pages.

**models.py**

```
class BlogListingPage(Page):
     blog_listing_title = models.CharField(...)
    ...    
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Add custom content to our context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['blog_pages'] = self.get_children().live()
        return context

class BlogDetailPage(Page):
    blog_title = models.CharField(...)
```

**views.py**

```
def blog(request):
    ...
    context = {'data': BlogListingPage.objects.all()}
    return render(request, url, context)
```

**blog_listing.html**

```
    {% for obj in data %}
        <h2>{{ obj.blog_listing_title }}</h2>
        {% for post in obj.blog_pages.all %}
            {{ post.specific.blog_title }}
            <br>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
```

The *blog_listing_title* appears correctly, but I cannot find out how to access the set of *blog_title*s

What should I do? I do not understand the structure of the PageQuerySet and how it is used by django to express the html elements

[EDIT] This used to work when I called the url directly. When I introduced views I had to add

> {% for obj in data %}

and that's when the detail disappeared

Comment: Do you have a ForeignKey from BlogDetailPage to BlogListingPage?

Comment: @HelenShy No I don't. But see edited question

Answer (score 0):

You may check it:

```
#models.py

class BlogListingPage(Page):
     blog_listing_title = models.CharField(...)
    ...    
    def get_context(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        """Add custom content to our context."""
        context = super().get_context(request, *args, **kwargs)
        context['blog_pages'] = BlogDetailPage.objects.live().child_of(self)

        return context

class BlogDetailPage(Page):
    blog_title = models.CharField(...)
```

Comment: Sorry. That makes no difference